# Centering Issue With "Nag-Menu" Design (css?)

Tags: jquery, css, menu, center

I have a css issue (I believe it is, maybe JavaScript?) with some stay-on-top "nag menu" code that I'm trying to adapt to our website design, to improve upon an existing static-menu (made with CSS on a UL/LI element, as is often done.)

The original code was from : 1stwebdesigner.com in a "tutorial" page called / tutorials / create-stay-on-top-menu-css3-jquery /

I've adapted it to our site (so far) on just one test page.

Our old-style menu can be seen on any current page, and the NEW version stay-on-top, nag-menu page for testing this is here:

http://www.detroitblackjackteam.com/team-play.htm

There's an identical page using the old menu at :

http://www.detroitblackjackteam.com/teamplay.htm

(Note the similar URL: just take out the hyphen in filename, teamplay.htm)

Everything's working mostly fine so far, except I noticed that the new version menu doesn't stay properly centered with the browser either zoomed-in or small screen (first noticed the problem checking the site on my iPhone but it also appears if you make the browser window very small and zoom-in on the menu... see screen capture example here:

http://www.detroitblackjackteam.com/files/ZoomProblem.jpg

---

I've been all over this, as much as I can figure out, poked and prodded it with FireBug in the browser, but cannot for the life of me see HOW to make BOTH menus stay centered in the same position.

It's probably something simple, but I'm just missing it :-(

Any help / ideas appreciated.  Also any ideas to clean up the code at all will be appreciated as I know I kind of cobbled this together from different sources and it's probably not the most efficient thing in the world, in it's current state... ;-)

Code blocks for CSS, HTML, and JavaScript copied below for reference:

CSS

```
.bevelmenu { font: bold 13px Arial;   text-align: center;     
    padding: 9px 0 5px;   margin: 0;   width: 100%;      } 
.bevelmenu li {   list-style: none;   display: inline;   } 
.bevelmenu li a { padding: 9px 7px;   text-decoration: none;   color: #aaaaaa; } 
.bevelmenu li a:hover { color: #93D48C; 
    background-image: url("menubg.gif"); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   background-position: center center;        } 
/*  CSS for stay-on-top menu  */ 
    #menu    { 
      white-space:nowrap; 
      height: 30px; 
      text-align: center; 
      background-image:url("menu-bar.png"); 
      background-repeat:repeat; 
      background-attachment:scroll;           } 
    #navi    { 
      white-space:nowrap; 
      height: 30px; 
      text-align: center;                     } 
    .default { 
      width: 100%;                            } 
    .fixed   { 
      width: 100%;   
      top: 0; 
      left: 0;  
      position: fixed;  
      z-index: 4; 
      box-shadow: 0 0 36px #afffff;  
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 36px #afffff;  
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 36px #afffff;      }
```

HTML

```
<div id="navi"> 
 <div id="menu" class="default"> 
  <ul class="bevelmenu">
   <li><a href="http://www.detroitblackjackteam.com/">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.detroitblackjackteam.com/bbs/">Forum</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.detroitblackjackteam.com/webmail.htm">Mail</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.detroitblackjackteam.com/cal.htm">Calendar</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.detroitblackjackteam.com/ratings/">Ratings</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.detroitblackjackteam.com/files/">Downloads</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.detroitblackjackteam.com/blog/">Blog</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.detroitblackjackteam.com/play/">Play!</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div><!-- close menu -->
</div><!-- close navi -->
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 var menu = $('#menu'),
  pos = menu.offset();
  $(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(this).scrollTop() > pos.top+menu.height() && menu.hasClass('default')){
     menu.fadeOut('fast', function(){
      $(this).removeClass('default').addClass('fixed').fadeIn('fast');
     });
   } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= pos.top && menu.hasClass('fixed')){
     menu.fadeOut('fast', function(){
      $(this).removeClass('fixed').addClass('default').fadeIn('fast');
     });
   }
  });
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any & all help/advice on this :-)

-DBJT

= - = - = - = - = - = - = - = - = - = - = - = - = - = - = - = - =

**Edit, Update**

I received a comment from the original developer of this code, who hasn't had time yet to really look at it for me, but still answered an email inquiry.  He said:

```
<!-- language: lang-none --> <!-- Copy From E-Mail Message -->
>>> That would suggest there's a problem with the offset 
>>> (menu is longer than the viewport when zoomed in, and the 
>>> script is not able to make a negative offset, to the menu 
>>> starts at 0 position in the viewport). Either that or it's 
>>> jQuery's fault. Well, not exactly fault, it's just that 
>>> there can be some compatibility issues; the script was 
>>> written over 3 years ago and uses an old version of jQuery 
>>> (newest at the time of writing), but browsers evolved 
>>> since then a lot. Some methods jQuery makes use of may 
>>> not be working correctly anymore...
```

So maybe it IS more complicated than I thought, something in JQuery... or... something...

No replies yet on my question here?

Really would appreciate anyone's thoughts or head's-up on this, any ideas how to narrow it down, where the issue might lie... even just a guess.

= - = - = - = - = - = - = - = - = - = - = - = - = - = - = - = - =

** Edit, Update Again ;) **

Forgot to mention this is using JQuery too... kinda important I guess, LOL

I added a 'jquery' tag to the question and note it's hitting the 1.4.2 version :

```
<script type="text/javascript"   
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" 
charset="utf-8">
</script>
```

Thanks, again, for ANYONE out there who can figure out what's goin' on here :)

-DBJT

Comment: Have you tried simply using a more recent version of jQuery?

Comment: Hi Skube, thanks for post.  I didn't try it before you asked (duh!) but just did this: http://www.detroitblackjackteam.com/team-play-jquery-1.10.2.min.htm  using the production version 1.10.2 and it's the same problem, nothing changed as far as I can see :(

Comment: Also tried with the JQuery 2.0.3 version (latest release, abandons support for some older IE versions so I really don't want to use it, but just for testing anyway here...) http://www.detroitblackjackteam.com/team-play-jquery-2.0.3.min.htm but unfortunately, again, no change apparent.  Problem remains.  So it's prob NOT any bug in JQ but still just the css/javascript code doing something wrong :(

Comment: You could use jQuery 1.9 if you'd like to support older IE. In terms of your original problem, is this only in Firefox that has the issue?

Comment: Same issue in all browsers far as I can tell. I've tested: Firefox Chrome Opera IE on XP/Vista/7 and Mac OSX  :(   Note it's only when the viewport is small & page zoomed-in (or using small screen like iPhone).  See screenshot image example...

Comment: Actually I just realized it's not necessary to ZOOM the page at all, to see this problem.  It seems to appear also if only the browser window-size is too NARROW (below some point of minimum width, the menu bar begins jumping to the non-centered position, from the normal and "on top" modes). With enough "width" however, everything is okay! I'm not sure how relevant this is, if at all (?)

Answer (score 0):

set CSS

.fixed{min-width: 542px;}

to make it similar in both the condition.

Comment: Wow... thanks! Finally after 2 months somebody figured this out.  

This HELPS a lot, but there still seems to be an issue with horizontal scrolling, left-right, when the browser window is very small.  

See screenshot here:  
http://www.detroitblackjackteam.com/files/menufix1.jpg

(Also, curious where you got the "542" value exactly?)

Comment: Oops forgot to say the demo page above with the min-width fix applied is here: http://detroitblackjackteam.com/team-play-fix1.htm